# How to provide different data to different users from a NodeJS web server?

Tags: node.js, express, architecture, dataset

We are building a website for visualizing large sets of data. The datasets are loaded on the server (NodeJS and Express) using **crossfilter.js** and by exposing different endpoints the data is sent to the website where the visualizations are getting built.

So far the server was only able to provide visualizations for the dataset that is loaded when the server starts. For changing the dataset, the server needs to be restarted. We are trying now to allow the user to change the dataset that he is visualizing. The problem is that we don't know what is the best approach. The necesary steps would be the next ones:

- The user provides the new dataset
- The server is loading this dataset without altering the datasets that the other users are using
- The server is able to provide to each user the right dataset.

Basically, our uncertainty is about how to load multiple datasets into memory. The server might become too overloaded.

Any advises?

Comment: I don't really have the expertise to answer this myself, but it might help the right people find this question if you mention how exactly you're storing/retrieving your data (as in, which database system are you using, etc). Put it in the tags, as well.

Comment: As I explained the data is coming from datasets (csv, json). Hence, we are not using any database system.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't familiar with that term being used for csv/json data, my bad.

Comment: How big are these datasets? Do you know the memory capacity of the servers hosting your application?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices here for memory management.  You can allocate enough memory for everything, and overflow to swap.  Or, more complicated, store the files on disk, and have the datasets follow a cache pattern.  Using a fixed size lru cache will allow as many datasets as you have disk space, with the caveat that returning users may have to wait a second or two while the dataset is read off of disk into memory.